# Backbone change event is not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am learning Backbone and struck at one place. I wanted to load model on page load. So I have below code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="poview"></div>
    <script id="poTemplate" type="text/template">
        <td><%= Ponumber %></td>
        <td><%= Posuppliername %></td>
        <td><%= Postatusname %></td>
        <td><%= Podate %></td>
        <td><%= DispOrderTotal %></td>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            var PO = Backbone.Model.extend()

            var POList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                url: 'po.json',
                model: PO,
                parse: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.PurchaseOrder)
                    return response.PurchaseOrder
                }
            })

            var POView = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: 'tr',
                template: $('#poTemplate').html(),
                initialize: function() {
                    _.bindAll(this, 'render')
                    this.model.bind('change', this.render)
                },
                events: {
                    'click': 'click'
                },
                render: function() {
                    console.log('po render')
                    var tmpl = _.template(this.template)
                    $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()))
                    return this;
                },
                click: function() {
                    console.log('clicked....')
                }
            })

            var POListView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $('#poview'),
                initialize: function() {
                    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'appendPO')
                    this.collection = new POList()
                    this.collection.bind('change', this.render, this)
                    this.collection.bind('add', this.render, this)
                    this.collection.fetch({add:true})
                },
                render: function() {
                    var self = this;
                    console.log(this.collection.models)
                    this.collection.each(function(po) {
                        self.appendPO(po)
                    }, this)
                },
                appendPO: function(po) {
                    var poView = new POView({
                        model: po
                    });
                    console.log(po)
                    $(this.el).append(poView.render().el)               
                }
            });

            var poListView = new POListView()

        })(jQuery)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is json response from server

```
{
    "@totalCount": "1134",
    "PurchaseOrder": [
        {
            "ID": "689600",
            "Ponumber": "K037412201",
            "Poname": "",
            "Podate": "2011-12-26T10:03:24.000+05:30",
            "Posuppliername": "XYZ UPS Supplier",
            "Postatusname": "Approved - Supplier Received",
            "DispOrderTotal": "$1.99"
        },
        {
            "ID": "689601",
            "Ponumber": "K037412202",
            "Poname": "",
            "Podate": "2011-12-26T10:03:24.000+05:30",
            "Posuppliername": "ABC UPS Supplier",
            "Postatusname": "Approved - Supplier Received",
            "DispOrderTotal": "$1.99"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when the page is loaded render method on POListView is not fired. What is issue in this code?

**Edit**

```
jQuery(function($){
  ...
});
```

If I use above convention also, that does not work.

**Working example**
Refer answer from @JayC

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="poview"></div>
    <script id="poTemplate" type="text/template">
        <td><%= Ponumber %></td>
        <td><%= Posuppliername %></td>
        <td><%= Postatusname %></td>
        <td><%= Podate %></td>
        <td><%= DispOrderTotal %></td>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function($) {
            var PO = Backbone.Model.extend({
                idAttribute: 'ID'
            })

            var POList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                url: 'po.json',
                model: PO,
                parse: function(response) {
                    console.log('parse')
                    return response.PurchaseOrder
                }
            })

            var POView = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: 'tr',
                template: $('#poTemplate').html(),
                initialize: function() {
                    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'click')
                },
                events: {
                    'click': 'click'
                },
                render: function() {
                    var tmpl = _.template(this.template)
                    $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()))
                    return this;
                },
                click: function() {
                    console.log('clicked.... ' + this.model.id)
                }
            })

            var POListView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $('#poview'),
                initialize: function() {
                    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'appendPO')
                    this.collection = new POList()
                    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this)
                    this.collection.fetch()
                },
                render: function() {
                    var self = this;
                    console.log(this.collection.models)
                    this.collection.each(function(po) {
                        self.appendPO(po)
                    }, this)
                },
                appendPO: function(po) {
                    var poView = new POView({
                        model: po
                    });
                    $(this.el).append(poView.render().el)               
                }
            });

            var poListView = new POListView()

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not seeing a binding to the `reset` event for your collection. The [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) documentation now has a FAQ which explains events *(finally!)* and you can see from it that
the `reset` event fires when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.  On collections, that's what `fetch` normally does.

Comment: Great. It is working now. I have made two changes. One that @JayC has suggested, using reset event and using Backbone 0.9.1 instead of 0.3.3. Not sure what was issue with 0.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this, which executes the function immediately, when the DOM is not yet ready/available:

```
(function($){
  ...
})(jQuery);
```

But probably you wanted to write this (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3 ), which delays the function until the document is ready to be manipulated (attach your views, etc):

```
jQuery(function($){
  ...
});
```

Of course, only the actual initialization call should be wrapped into `jQuery()`, the other parts can remain in the plain closure.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I have log output in render method that is also not printed.

Comment: Actually, enough of the DOM is loaded.  I've seen a few backbone examples where the scripts ti initialize was placed toward the end of the body and, they work (indeed, I think my project works that way... all the definitions are at top but the script to initialize is included at the bottom).  Why should we do that? I'm not sure.  I have read somewhere that adding multiple DOMReady functions actually can slow down a page but I'm not sure that was the reason.